# Get the rows, where day is equal to some value

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a field with type= `date` in MySQL DB.

It store dates in `YY-m-d` format.

How can I write a query which will get the rows where day is equal to some value, for example `1`?
I need to get only first days of months (`2009-11-01, 2009-12-01, 2010-01-01...`)

Thanks

Comment: it store dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, i believe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [DAYOFMONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) function in the query.

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE DAYOFMONTH(<the-date-column>) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) method also

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d") = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using `like` operator:

```
select <columns> from <table> where <the-date-column> like  '%-01'
```

Comment: That wouldn't work... day() (synonym for dayofmonth) returns just the day, so the '-01' would never match, I'm afraid.

Comment: that was my bad... I have corrected it.
I completely agree DAYOFMONTH is best in this case, I have just provided alternative approach.

Comment: Removed my downvote after the correction - alternatives are always good to know, as long as it's been made clear that it's not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

DAYOFMONTH is the way to go.